# I can't print my entire csv file in python on OnlineGDB

Tags: python, csv, file, printing

I'm trying to print a csv file on OnlineGDB. However, when I do, I can only print the first and last column and 5 rows. It also prints [5 rows X 6 columns] at the very end. Although this is not terrible, my csv file contains over a thousand rows and 6 columns. Is there anyway I can print the entirety of my csv file?

Here's my code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
    print(df.head())
```

This prints

```
      time_s    ...     speed_mph
0     0         ...     0
1     1         ...     0
2     2         ...     0
3     3         ...     0
4     4         ...     0
```

Comment: Reading the docs [head](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html?highlight=head#pandas.DataFrame.head) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pandas function to show all columns

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That helped me print all the columns. However, I still only have 5 rows. Is there anyway I could display more rows?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the code for displaying max rows as well